# g++ mistake the meaning of rdi and rsi register

Tags: google-chrome, gcc, clang, cpu-registers

First of all, i make use of clang++ to generate one library named libbase-core.so.
Then i wrote one main.cc.

```
#include <string>
#include "base/single_thread_task_runner.h"
#include "base/threading/thread.h"
base::Thread Appthread("AppThread");
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Appthread.Start();
  scoped_refptr<base::SingleThreadTaskRunner> task_runner =
      Appthread.task_runner();
   return 0;
}
```

My build command is `/usr/bin/g++ -DNDEBUG -g -I/usr/include/libchrome/ main_menu.cc -o bluetoothtbd_socketclient /lib/libbase-core.so`

At last when i run the bluetoothtbd_socketclient, it crash becase of access page0 memory.

By deeply analyze, i found before excute task_runner = Appthread.task_runner();
i checked some registers, i found there are something wrong, rdi and rsi should replace, then righ.

## rdi register store the address of local variable task_runner

## rsi register store the address of object Appthread

The following picture shows the related disassemble code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lUjZ.png)

Anyone who can provide some help, very appreciate.
Thanks.

By deeply analyze, i found before excute task_runner = Appthread.task_runner();
i checked some registers, i found there are something wrong, rdi and rsi should replace, then righ.

## rdi register store the address of local variable task_runner

## rsi register store the address of object Appthread